# Weird situation in python tkinter, can someone explain?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning on python 3x and using tkinter. When i am trying to test the global variable and local variable situation using tkinter button widget. The local variable i set was BIG CAPITAL X, and when i try to print the big capital X before the mainloop ends (it should come out error because the big X is local variable in makegui function but it prints out SMALL CAPITAL x. So as the second print(X) after the mainloop(). I tried with out alphabert to replace X, the same things happen on Y but error when i use alphabert G, H...

Why?

[Weird output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXk1O.png)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the code that's involved along with the expected and actual output [edit]ed into the question as text.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the docs of tkinter.

Comment: NONE of your "X" values are being used.  The `tkinter` module contains a variable called `X` which happens to have the value "x".  That's what you are printing.  You got that because of `from tkinter import *`, which is why that construct is discouraged.

Comment: Also you are trying to make a button without initialising the `Tk()`

Comment: Now i understand. Thanks Tim~

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs of `tkinter`, you first need to declare a `Tkinter.Tk()` variable, then create all your buttons, and then pack them in your variable at last the `mainloop`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def handler(A, B):
    print(A)
    print(B)


top = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(top, text = 'Hi', command = ( lambda :handler(X, "spam") ))
btn.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not use wildcard imports in the case of Tkinter. Use alias imports like `import tkinter as tk`. And your answer does not solve the OP's problem. You are merely showing how to make a tkinter GUI.